# Tensorflow estimator multiple GPU prediction

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator, multi-gpu

I have an estimator that can train and eval using multiple GPU through specifying `train_distribute` and `eval_distribute` in config. But there's no `predict_distribute` argument in `tf.estimator.RunConfig`. How can I predict using multiple GPU?

Comment: Did you try  tf.contrib.estimator.replicate_model_fn?

Comment: No, because `tf.contrib.estimator.replicate_model_fn` is deprecated.

Comment: @JayYip Did you ever find a solution for this?